# Angular 4 select option auto populate from page load, does not work with ngModel

Tags: angular

I have update/edit feature page, where page loads/populates with existing values from DB so that user can change and update-submit.

All other controls working fine except `<select>` dropdown when I put `[(ngModel)] =""` in select tag, but if I remove ngModel then it populates values correctly.

But I need to bind selected value, so ngModel comes in where it fails. Below is my code

Plunk URL - https://plnkr.co/edit/HqCOOE4fg3nmwssOXIz3?p=preview

```
<select [(ngModel)]="selectedItem" name="kannelSettingsId" class="form-control">
   <option *ngFor="let item of kannelList;let index=index; trackBy:trackByIdx()" [value]="item.kannelSettingsId" [selected]="item.kannelSettingsId === bind.kannelSettings.kannelSettingsId">
      {{item.server}}
   </option>              
</select>
```

Comment: Well, you need to set the initial value to selectedItem (the value you want preselected), otherwise of course `selectedItem` cannot be found from the array.  ngModel overrides the `[selected]` in this case

Comment: I see you added plunker. Did you even try what I suggested?

Answer (score 1):

@AJT-82 , Yes I tried that too even I tried with dummy values but no success.

But its  WORKING now - by adding #bindForm="ngForm" & #kannelSettingsId="ngModel"

```html
<form class="form-horizontal" #bindForm="ngForm">
   <select required minlength="1" #kannelSettingsId="ngModel" 
          [(ngModel)]="bind.kannelSettings.kannelSettingsId" 
                name="updateKannelSettingsId" class="form-control">
      <option *ngFor="let item of kannelList;"
         [value]="item.kannelSettingsId" 
         [selected]="item.kannelSettingsId === bind.kannelSettings.kannelSettingsId">
       
       {{item.server}}
      
      </option>              
   </select>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Found this problem and for my future reference and for people who need it!

Note: Works for reactive forms!

**Easy and Effective!**

```
 <select class="form-control" [compareWith]="compareByOptionId"  formControlName="kannelSettingsId">
      <option *ngFor="let item of kannelList" [ngValue]="item">{{item.server}}</option>
 </select>
```

and on component file add this method

```
compareByOptionId(idFist, idSecond) {
  return idFist.id === idSecond.id;
}
```